# how can i send a canvas image using vb.net email

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html

i convert a SVG to canvas using canvg to an image and then vb.net client side i convert the image to bytearray() and saved it to a folder on my server so i can attached by email :

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path = Server.MapPath("PDFs\")
    Dim fileNameWithPath As String = path + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "-").Replace(":", "") + ".jpeg"
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(fileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create)
    Dim bw As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(fs)
    Dim ByteArray() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(hfChartImg.Value)
    bw.Write(ByteArray)
    bw.Close()

    Dim file As String = fileNameWithPath
    Dim message As New MailMessage()
    message.From = New MailAddress("****************")
    message.To.Add(New MailAddress("***************"))
    message.Subject = "new image "
    message.Body = "this is the apak chart img"
    Dim data As New Attachment(file)
    message.Attachments.Add(data)
    Dim client As New SmtpClient()
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("***************", "*******")
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Port = 587
    client.Send(message)
End Sub
```

this code works fine and it send the image .

actually i don't need to save this image to my server i just wanted to send it without saving , this is what i have done so far

```
 Protected Sub emailSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles emailSend.Click
    Dim customerChoice As String = DropDownList1.Text
    Select Case customerChoice
        Case "pdf"
            MsgBox("select pdf ")
        Case "image"
            Dim imageFile As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim bw As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(imageFile)
            Dim bytearray() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(hfChartImg.Value)
            bw.Write(bytearray)
```

am i very far from doing what i want ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write

```
Dim data As New Attachment(New MemoryStream(ByteArray), "SomeName")
```

Comment: do i need a memorystream at all

Comment: @MinaGabriel: Yes; `Attachment` does not have a constructor that takes a raw `byte[]`.

Comment: this will send the bytearray as unknow file type i thisnk i need to convert the bytearray to an image first right

Comment: @MinaGabriel: No; you just need to pass a MIME type as the third parameter.

Comment: i don't really know how to do this ??? if you have a link or example that will be great

Comment: @MinaGabriel: How to do what? How to pass a third parameter? SVGs are `image/svg+xml`.